# Where to ask questions about fashion information?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need know fashion show information, model, goods.

Is there a fashion Stack Overflow?

Comment: All of the available Stack Exchange sites can be found at http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 5):

There is no fashion Stack Exchange site.

You can always suggest one on [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), if the [existing suggestion](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72725/fashion) doesn't fit what you are looking for, or follow/commit to it if it does.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you think there should be head over to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and if there's one proposed follow it. If there isn't a proposal create one.